# I feel like I have NOT been well filtered :-(

Tags: discussion

I answered a question about a mouse scrolling problem.

[mouse auto scrolling problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945058/mouse-auto-scrolling-problem/1024418#1024418)

The very first and most important part of my answer was :

### "There seems to be an incompatibility that has been added to one of the latest updates."

Followed by an explanation as to why I say so :

> "Until just a few days ago, everything went well with my mouse, plugged into a usb hub and working perfectly with my cell on a docking station, my windows computer AND my Ubuntu 17.10 computer.
>
> Since a few days, ONLY my ubuntu computer goes WILD scrolling ONE FULL PAGE at a time instead of the normal line by line scroll..."

One thing I noticed I didn't do was add that until a fix is found, that I just bought another mouse at the dollar store.

Result?

My answer was deleted by anonymous2 with the reason :

"This does not really answer the question."

If this doesn't answer the question what does?

Go back to my point #1 :

### "There seems to be an incompatibility that has been added to one of the latest updates."

Must we start having people filtering filterers???? :-(

No offense anonymous2 but I DID answer the answer.

I would have discussed it in private with this person, but was unable to find a contact link on his or her profile.

**So THE QUESTION IS :**

Do I repost my answer and risk anonymous2 filtering it again???

Or do I just stop answering questions that I COULD have helped with, but didn't because of potentially having my answers deleted.

=====

**Update**

OK, so as a newbie here, I made a bunch of mistakes.

- I didn't see the info about Thomas Ward deleting my response, making me think that anonymous2, mentionned a bit lower, was the person who had deleted it.
- I used the term "filter" to mean that a person (mod) deleted it.
- I used caps, being surprised and a bit frustrated that an update could cause a downgrade. When I Googled "Ubuntu 17.10 scrolling problem" and filtered the answers to less than a week, since my problem appeared after an upgrade within a week, I did find a few mentions of exactly the same symptoms as I had, that right after an update, the mouse reaction had changed.
- I thought that my response was an answer, since it does explain why suddenly out of no where mice start going wild, scrolling awkwardly. Now I know that an answer here needs to bring a solution, which in my case didn't bring one.
- I may have speculated, since I didn't find anything on the web about a bug. But since the problem is fresh in my case, that the only thing that happened on my ubuntu computer that was well timed with the arrival of the was problem is an update, I added 1+1. As mentionned above, I did find on Google a few mentions from other people that the problem arrived right after an update.

In short, we are all humans and make mistakes. Maybe Thomas, if he saw that I'm a newbie, could have elaborated a bit why he deleted my response, and maybe I could have been a bit less "reactive" to it. ;-)

So the problem remains that there seems to have been an update that causes certain mice to go wild.

Is there a place where I can report the symptoms to have a review of what could have been updated to cause such a problem?

Comment: *Is there a place where I can report the symptoms...?* Yes :) See [How do I report a bug?](//askubuntu.com/q/5121)

Answer (score 8):

First, your post was removed by a moderator, not the user you suggest.

This is not a filter, it is community quality control, a very important part of how Ask Ubuntu works.

Your "answer" is full of caplocks and shouting for Ubuntu to fix this now!!! how is that an answer? it is not, it is a me too post and they get deleted. If you have a question that is not answered, ask it, that is what the site is for BUT...

> "There seems to be an incompatibility that has been added to one of
>   the latest updates."

is not an answer in any way, it is a reply to or comment on the question, an answer should offer a solution to a problem, rather than just reply to it, I hope you see the difference between the two?

As you are new here, you should [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and read the help pages on [asking](https://askubuntu.com/help/asking) and [answering](https://askubuntu.com/help/answering), so you understand the site a bit more.

Comment: Also the sentence "*There seems to be an incompatibility that has been added to one of the latest updates.*" sounds *very* speculative, not at all supported by any substantial bug-report or discussion or something like that.